# How to reduce Internet usage for Updating Ubuntu?

Tags: upgrade

For better performance Ubuntu needs updating.  But it consumes Internet usage too much. A solution is needed for this. It will be helpful to those who are unaware of the Changes/Description given in 'Update Manager'. Unwanted updating is useless.

Comment: I think you should add the procedure below. Check [Can I answer my own question](http://askubuntu.com/help/self-answer).

Comment: I followed the procedure and edited the question.

Answer (score 1):

Remove unwanted items using Synaptic Package Manager.  It will warn you what other items will be removed along with it.  You can also use Ubuntu Software Center to remove some items.

If you don't use webmail, remove Thunderbird. If you don't use remote desktop, remove Remmina. If you don't play the default games then remove them also. If you don't use Libreoffice eliminate them as well. If you only use the word processor then replace it with Abiword. If you only use the spreadsheet application install Gnumeric and remove Libreoffice.

Select necessary items only for Updates in 'Software Sources'.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by proceeding this way:

Create a new file on apt-get conf with(have to be with this exaclty name):

```
sudo touch /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/76download
```

And fill it with this content(**sudo nano /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/76download**):

```
Acquire
{
Queue-mode "access";
http
{
Dl-Limit "xx";
};
};
```

Where xx is the bandwidth you want in **KiloBytes**.